# UiTextView String Trim after Device Orientation

Tags: uitextview, uideviceorientation

i am creating an iPad app. When i changing the device orientation, after go to Landscape mode and again Portraint mode the value inside UiTextView not showing correctly.

[image of landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0wtR.png)

[image of portrait mode again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhKBP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the below function. It invoke when changing the device orientation.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // code for reload data })
    } 
    else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // code for reload data })
    }}
```